# Node - Electron Packager

Tags: npm, terminal, electron, cross-platform, electron-packager

i am currently trying to package my app using electron-packager,

first of all, when i test my app using:

```
node index.js <command>
```

everything works as expected!

What is so special about my application is that i just want an executable which you can run from the terminal, like:

```
./executable command
```

When i run:

```
electron-packager . --out=builds --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --app-version=1.0.0
```

It creates the executable, but when i execute the command in terminal, it hangs there forever and doesnt return... no idea why..

any suggestions?

thanks and greetings!

Comment: Enable the devTools and recreate you will be able to debug

Comment: hey sorry, what i actually wanted to do is: I want my electron packaged app to run from terminal like: *./executable* . I dont want it to start a gui, just stay in the cli, any suggestions?